# Query or Filter function help. Return list of values when A:A is not found in B:B

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a self contained formula (meaning no helper cells) to return a list of values that are NOT found within another range.

I have a list of values contained in Data!A:C

I have a list of values in FilterDoNotIncludes!A:A

I need to return a list of values from Data!A:C where Data!A:A is NOT found in FilterDoNotIncludes!A:A.

I need to avoid using helper formulas so this must all be contained in one formula. I'm thinking either query or filter formulas will work best but I've tried a few things without success. I know I could create a Query formula that includes where not Data!A:A includes FilterDoNotIncludes!A2 but I want to avoid referencing specific cells.

Here's a sheet I've been working with https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ZiOVwZQl713_nDB2-VDNU2JcQtaanJ8g_UqiDslPpU/edit#gid=552207544

Comment: You need to share access

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
 =query(arrayformula(iferror(if(match(Data!A2:C,FilterDoNotInclude!A2:A,0)>0,""),Data!A2:C)),"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col1<>''")
```